# How to trim first name to a single character?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column that has data stored in full name format, for example:

> Tom Smith
>
> Andrew Smith

Is there a function (or combination of functions) I can use to turn this into the following:

> T. Smith
>
> A. Smith

Comment: Will all names be First Last? No middle names?

Comment: You're assuming that someone's first name can't contain a space, or that they only have one first name. While this may be true for your data it won't always be true. Push for a change in the SQL design.

Comment: @Seph Not required - this is for a once off data transfer (moving from a legacy to a new system) and I've checked the data :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *should* be storing first name and last name separately. In the meantime:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FullName LIKE '% %' THEN 
  LEFT(FullName, 1) + '.' + SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), 255)
    ELSE FullName END
  FROM dbo.table;
```

Another alternative:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LEFT(FullName, 1) 
  + '.' + SUBSTRING(FullName, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), 0), 255), 
  FullName)
FROM dbo.table;
```

Both of these deal with single-word names like `Prince` or `Madonna` - but they won't properly handle cases where you have middle names. The problem in that case will be:

```
John Wayne Bobbitt
Billy Ray Cyrus
Lisa Van der Wal
Lee Harvey Oswald
Dennis Moseley Williams
James de Caan
```

How do you determine which of those are middle names and which have multi-word last names? If you're dealing with this situation, start shaking your fists harder.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I wasn't involved in the design process. *shakes fist at DBA team*

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @t table(FullName Varchar(100))
Insert Into @t Values('Tom Smith'),('Andrew Smith'),('  Andrew '),('John Wayne Bobbitt'),(NULL)
```

**--Solution**

```
SELECT 
    NewName = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName))) > 0 THEN LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName)),1)
              + '.'
              +SUBSTRING((LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName))),CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName))),LEN(FullName))
         ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName))
    END
FROM @t
```

//Result

**NewName**

```
T. Smith
A. Smith
Andrew
J. Wayne Bobbitt
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(nameCol, 1, 1) + '.' + SUBSTRING(nameCol, CHARINDEX(' ', nameCol), 100)
```

Comment: Note that this will turn 'Prince' into 'P.Prince' - the OP didn't state whether there might be values missing a space.

Comment: @AaronBertrand OP didn't answer my question whether all names will be First Last. Went under the assumption that they would be.

Comment: I'm just making sure it's understood, not necessarily as a correction but for other readers who come across the answer (and may not have the same requirements as the OP).